# copy a php file from another server

Tags: php, file, copy

I am writing a version update procedure. The customer site reads a file from the my server and extracts the data into an array. After a version compare, if it contains php file names, then I want to copy those files from my Server onto their server.
Using this technique I also update any database changes.
This is to stream-line the updates and avoid me having to FTP the updates. I have it working up to reading the file names. Can I do a file copy or do I have to do a ftp_get. The php file itself may be in use. I was hoping not to hand over the password. This is a product that will be distributed on many sites.

Comment: If the authentication is not involved in the process, everyone will have an access to your php files. I bet this is definitely what you want. To avoid supplying passwords you could try to use `sftp` with key authorization.

Comment: This is open source, so do I care if they have access?

Comment: Then why not to run the separate ftp server with “updates,” allowing anonymous access and simply ftp it w/out password?

Comment: what about SVN or GIT?